# Stop file_exist calling error if no file is being uploaded

Tags: php

Is there a simple way to stop file_exists from returning true when a user hasn't chosen to upload a file as part of a form?

I have the following code;

```
if (isset($_FILES["tipimage"]) && $_FILES["tipimage"]["error"] == 0) {
    $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
    $filename = $_FILES["tipimage"]["name"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["tipimage"]["type"];
    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $filename;

    // Verify file extension
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) {
        $error .= "Invalid File Format<br>";
    } 
}

if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["tipimage"]["name"])) {
    $error .= "The File " . $_FILES["tipimage"]["name"] . " already exists.<br>";
} else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["tipimage"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)) {
    $successmsg .= "<div class='alert alert-success'>Image - " . $filename . " - Uploaded Successfully!</div>";
}
```

Comment: yea! Put the test in a sensible place, like inside the previous IF that checks if they actually uploaded a file.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Wrap your last if statement in the first if state the one that check if there is an image. If there is no image don't check to see if a file exists!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your `else` condition as you have used `if` and `else if`. I would go with multiple if possible to avoid errors.

```
// Check if the file exists
if(file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["tipimage"]["name"])){
    $error .= "The File " . $_FILES["tipimage"]["name"] . " already exists.<br>";
} 

// Upload file
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["tipimage"]["tmp_name"], 'uploads/' . $_FILES["file_upload"]["name"])){
    die('Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.');
}
 $successmsg .= "<div class='alert alert-success'>Image - " . $filename . " - Uploaded Successfully!</div>";

// Check for errors
if($_FILES["file_upload"]["error"] > 0){
    die('An error ocurred when uploading.');
}
```